Does this argument refute Islam?
The Qur'an is full of verses where it tells you that Allah loves you if X. That is, on one condition.
For example, in Sura 3 Ayah 32, it is said that "Allah does not love those who do not believe".
And, that Allah's love is conditional, makes me think something...
Allah is supposed to be the highest conceivable being, isn't He? If you can find a being who has more perfection than Allah, that being is the one who is God (not the other).
For example, if there is a being more perfect than Allah, Allah would no longer be God, because God by definition is perfection and the absolute.
Okay, so God is the perfection of good. OK, and the ultimate moral perfection, love, right? Because there is no greater expression of kindness than love.
So, if Allah is God, he should show the highest degree of love possible and no being could surpass him (since he is God). But the Qur'an says that Allah's love is partial and conditional, the expression of his love is not total and perfect (he does not love everyone, and he only loves you if you repent, and go with him).
If Allah does not show the highest degree of love possible, he is not perfect, then he is not God?
In Christianity it is not so, Christ loves even his enemies. Christ died on the cross loving those who crucified and killed Him. Hence the famous phrase "Father, forgive them, they do not know what they are doing".
Or even in the Sermon on the Mount, where Christ said that "blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the Kingdom of Heaven."Or "blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they will be satisfied."
The love of the Christian God is absolute and unconditional, God loves us all.
How is this argument refuted?

Why is there Hellfire even in Christianity if God loves everybody unconditionally? If you can answer this you'll find were you interpreted wrong.

@Medi1Saif Although God loves everyone, even those who do not do good, paradise and hell are considered places where divine justice is manifested based on people's actions and decisions during their earthly life. Hell is considered a place of punishment for those who have lived in sin, rejected divine guidance and committed injustices. It is a state of separation from God and suffering that reflects the consequence of evil deeds. The existence of paradise and hell serves as a divine justice system that balances God's love and mercy with the responsibility and consequences of human actions.

@Medi1Saif If you are a dad and you punish your child because he has done something wrong, it does not mean that you hate him ...

Okay, so God is the perfection of good. OK, and the ultimate moral perfection, love, right? Because there is no greater expression of kindness than love.
This is a faulty premise. What gave you the right to define that? For your information, Islamic theology is on majority, anti moral-realist or quasi-realist. We don't believe in moral realism. I.e., we don't believe things can be good or bad independent of God's orders, neither do we believe they can be good or evil independent of them. God can throw all Prophets and saints in hell, while giving paradise to satan, and he would still be

all-just and most compassionate. His attributes are eternal and transcendent above creation. He was the creator before he created anything and he was the most loving before there was any creation for him to reflect his love upon.

So it is simply your own perception that perfect love must be unconditional, God does not place such an image upon himself. The concept of right or wrong, or justice or injustice of a Muslim is defined by the orders of Allah, and not vice versa.

Alex Iglesias so you've answered your question by yourself, the statements in qur'an are referring to the hereafter since there some of Allah's creation will face his punishment.

@Medi1Saif Worth mentioning that under Annihilationism and Christian conditionalism, it's not so clear that there is hellfire.


In Christianity it is not so, Christ loves even his enemies. Christ
died on the cross loving those who crucified and killed Him. Hence the
famous phrase "Father, forgive them, they do not know what they are
doing".

You are assuming that Christ is god? Christ also said "father why do you forsake me..." How can a loving god forsake his own Prophet?

In Matthew 27:46, it does not imply that God really abandoned Jesus in an absolute sense, but that Jesus, in his humanity, experienced the feeling of desolation and separation from God while carrying the weight of sin and the redemption of humanity on the cross. This reflects the deep suffering and emotional anguish that Jesus experienced as part of His sacrifice for humanity.
